# python re module to replace the binary data inside a text file?

Tags: python, regex, binary, content-type

I know mixing text and binary is awful, but I have to do this.

I want to replace the binary content, which is around with "Content-Type: image" and "----", by string "XXXXXXXX"

So the code for test is:

```
# coding=utf-8
import re
raw_data = open('r_img.txt').read()
#data = re.sub(r"Content-Type: image.*?-----","Content-Type: imageXXXXXXX-----", raw_data, re.S)
data = re.sub(r"Content-Type: image[^-]*-----","Content-Type: imageXXXXXXX-----", raw_data, re.S)
print data
```

And the file r_img.txt would be:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="commodity_pic1"; filename="C:\Documents and Settings\tim\My Documents\My Pictures\Pic\222A8888.jpg"

Content-Type: image/pjpeg



EEE? JFIF  H H  EEE C 

EEE C       

 EEEWhfEEE[e?EEEEEEqEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEZIOEEE(r5?-iEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE?EEE?EEEEEE
-----------------------------7db27132d0198
```

I had try string.replace() and re.sub, but I can't still find the answer.

Comment: Why would you not use Python's multipart MIME capabilities?

Comment: For some reason, I have to extract some product information from mysql database, then construct a SOAP request and use python's suds library to send this SOAP request to a remote server.

But some of the information extract is combine with binary data and text data

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie on python, and I have never heard Python's multipart MIME before. Thanks for your advice, I will try to google for some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
data = re.sub(r"Content-Type: image.*-----","Content-Type: imageXXXXXXX-----", 
              raw_data, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

Essentially it matches in a greedy way all characters between `Content-Type: image` and `-----`. The 0 means "match all occurrences of this pattern". Probably this is superfluous for you, but you can't skip it as you also wanted to use the flag `re.DOTALL` that modify the meaning of "any characters" to also include newlines.

HTH!